# Resetting State in React with saved initial State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to save State twice, so I can reset it later on, but no matter what method I try, the 'setFullTrials' won't update with the saved data. The "console.log(savedData)" shows that all the data is there, so that's definitely not the problem. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
function AllTrials({Trialsprop}) {
        let [savedData, setSavedData] = useState([]);
        let [fullTrials, setFullTrials] = useState([]);
        useEffect(() => {
          //Call the Database (GET)
            fetch("/trials") 
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(json => {
                // upon success, update trials
                console.log(json);
                setFullTrials(json);
                setSavedData(json);
              })
              .catch(error => {
                // upon failure, show error message
              });
          }, []);
          


    const resetState = () => {
          setFullTrials(savedData);
          //setFullTrials((state) => ({
            ...state,
            savedData
          }), console.log(fullTrials));
          // setFullTrials(savedData.map(e => e));
          console.log("savedData", savedData)
      }
```

Comment: How do you know that the fullTrials is not updated?

Comment: Where do you call `resetState`? Showing the full code would be helpful

Comment: Your code works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-grass-ov9xdf?file=/src/App.js The only "problem" is that you're logging the updated state too early since state changes are asynchronous

Comment: Duplicate: [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG I'm new to React and have only used the functional component way of doing things, not the class component so I did read that duplicate but didn't fully understand it.

Comment: It works the same

Comment: Yeah, class/functional doesn't really matter; updates to a state are batched and executed soon in the future, not immediately. Logging a state right after setting it will show the old value. The best way to look at state during debugging is to add `<pre>{JSON.stringify(someStateVar, null, 2}</pre>` to your component, this will always show the current state right in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, it will likely run before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(fullTrials)
   // Whatever else we want to do after the state has been updated.
}, [fullTrials])
```

This `console.log` will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

- Note: "fullTrials" in the example is interchangeable with whatever other state piece you're dealing with.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more info.

**P.S:** the correct syntax for `useState` is with `const`, not `let`.
i.e. - `const [state, setState] = useState()`

Comment: Please check for duplicates before posting answers. 99.9% of JavaScript questions are dupes (or typos)